# Using integrated webcam after updating for youcam software

Tags: windows-7, updates, webcam, hardware-failure

My webcam doesn't work since 2 months ago.I tried to resolve the problem but I couldn't yet.

at first,I tried to update my webcam driver but I couldn't find the location of webcam.In my device manager I can't see any image devices e.g. webcam ,...
When I open the youcam software this message is shown :" Warning.no webcam detected.if you are
using an integrated camera,make sure that it is turned on"
My laptop is hp pavilion dv6 notebook(6080se) and My OS is Win7.

Thanks for your advice....

Comment: Is your webcam is a built in or a usb cam?

Answer (score 0):

It is a typical issue for this model.
The issue is with the flexible cable that goes to the camera and its contacts.
Of course, first you need to check whether the camera is detected in the Device Manager.
Go there and expand Imaging devices and check if you see you camera there. if It is not there - it is either not detected on the hardware level, or drivers are not installed.
If you see any items with yellow ! mark - you need to install drivers.
If you do not see the device at all - it not connected firmly.

You'll need small disassembling.

1. Remove the front panel near the camera - it is sticked to the display, be accurate!
2. near the camera you'll see a small white square - it is cable that goes to the camera. Try to move it up to make a better contact.
3. After that camera should be detected in the Device manager.